# How can i reference jquery ui icons on my website . . 

Tags: jquery-ui, icons

is there anyway to reference jquery ui icons as regular images anywhere in my site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you've linked to the jquery CSS, you can get at the icons by applying the `.ui-icon` base class and the specific icon class (e.g - .ui-icon-close for close button) to your element (usually span)

The jquery wiki has a comprehensive list of icons and their classes, you can find it here : http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137970/jQuery-UI-CSS-Framework

Just inspect the icon and get the class.

**EDIT**

Sample usage

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin"></span> <!-- Shows a magnifying glass -->
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-play"></span> <!-- Shows a play button -->
```

Comment: can you give an example of referencing it as a regular image ??

Comment: @ooo By regular image do you mean something like `<img src='path/to/image'>`? If so, no. jQuery uses CSS sprites so you'd have to do it that way. Added sample usage.

Comment: it also helps to overwrite ui-icon style from block to inline-block

Comment: You can also do `<span class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close"></span></span>` - this gived the border/button look. You could then bind a jquery .hover() event to toggle the ui-hover-state class on the outer span, eg: `jQuery('.ui-state-default').hover(function() { $(this).toggleClass('ui-state-hover'); })`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this code snipplet: http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/773/

Answer (score 0):

you can use icon classes from [jQueryUI Icons Cheatsheet](http://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/jqueryui-icons)